# A simple console while loop that captures the console input and prints to console not working

Tags: scala

Why does the below code when run in sbt just print out continuously...

```
[Info] command:null
[Info] command:null
[Info] command:null
[Info] command:null
```

I thought readline will block until I enter something in the console.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    
    var command = ""
    while (command != "exit") {
      command = scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
      println(s"command: $command")

    }

  }
```

If I paste this into ammonite it works as expected, it waits for my input that outputs it to the console.  Typing "exit" exits the application.

Comment: Maybe you are running your task in forked mode? I assume you are running this with `run`. Try toggling this setting: `Compile / run / fork := true`.

Comment: https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Forking.html

Comment: @yǝsʞǝla yes I am forking, i need forking to be set to `true`

Comment: @Blankman re. "I need forking to be set to true": No you don't. What you have here is an instance of an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 2):

SBT docs (https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Forking.html) describe the issue of input handling when forking:

> By default, the standard input of the sbt process is not forwarded to
> the forked process. To enable this, configure the `connectInput`
> setting:

```
run / connectInput := true
```

To disable forking use something like this:

```
Compile / run / fork := false
```

or:

```
fork := false
```